# Why the type is Char -> Char -> Char

Tags: haskell

I have following type signature:

```
*Main Lib> let f :: a -> a -> a -> a; f = undefined  
*Main Lib> let x :: Char; x = undefined
```

so to find out, which result type would I get, I did:

```
*Main Lib> :t f x
f x :: Char -> Char -> Char
```

Why not

```
Char -> Char -> Char -> Char
```

Because of the first parameter is already with `x` substituted?

Comment: Because the type of function application is `(a -> b) -> a -> b`, not `(a -> b) -> a -> (a -> b)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, exactly. Consider a different function, `length :: [a] -> Int`. If you ask for the type of `length "abc"`, you get `Int`:

```
Prelude> :t length "foo"
length "foo" :: Int
```

In general, if you have a function `f :: A -> B` and an argument `x :: A`, then `f x :: B`.

In your case we have `f :: a -> (a -> a -> a)` (specialized to `a = Char`), so `A = Char` and `B = Char -> Char -> Char`.

(`a -> a -> a -> a` is the same as `a -> (a -> a -> a)` because `->` in types is right associative.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

It's because `f x` is the function `f` with its first parameter already applied, so it only needs two more to get the result. This is called *currying*.

In Haskell, there isn't really any such thing as a function with three parameters. `a -> a -> a -> a` means "A function which takes an `a` and returns a function which takes an `a` and returns a function which takes an `a` and returns an `a`".

That's a lot of a mouthful to write out, so just put some parens in and it gets clearer: `a -> (a -> (a -> a))`.

So `f x` gives you `a -> (a -> a)`. It just so happens that Haskell's syntax allows you to say `f x y z` and act like you're calling a function with three parameters and that the compiler's smart enough not to construct all those intermediate curried functions when it doesn't need to.